# Mapbox performance - seperate layers vs setData vs filters

Tags: performance, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there any guidance information with regards to handling fairly large (5MB) GeoJSON datasets in mapbox?

I have 3-4 which I need to show and switch between on one map. Am I best to combine the data sources and use a `filter` on the layer to select the data I want? or would it be better to create 3-4 layers and show/hide based on need? or would it be best to have a single layer and feed in the data via `setData` on the layer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question depends on what your performance bottleneck is:

- If your bottleneck is transferring data to/from the worker threads, using `setFilter` will eliminate the need to transfer data to the worker threads.
- If your bottleneck is filtering data in the worker threads and you can preprocess that data more efficiently, using `setData` will eliminate the need to filter data on the worker threads.
- If you have lots of memory available and need to show/hide layers quickly, creating 3-4 separate layers and showing/hiding based on need will be best

Your bottleneck will depend on your data, your usage patterns, and your device. As always, I recommend doing whatever is easiest & profiling if perf isn'f good enough!

Comment: Thanks for the info Lucas. Excuse my niaivity but I'm not sure what you mean by transferring data into and out of the worker threads as I wasn't consciously aware of using worker threads. Can you elaborate a little? My impression of the performance bottleneck is that it's the client side rendering but I'm not 100% would welcome any tips on measuring and identifying bottlenecks in mapbox in particular.

Comment: I have the same question, and would love more clarification @lucas-wojciechowski about how to measure whether the bottleneck is transferring data to/from worker threads or filtering inside worker threads. @dougajmcdonald my understanding is that `mapbox-gl-js` uses worker threads internally.